# Nvidia driver curiously only loads properly when booting in recovery mode (Not blacklisted, secure boot disabled)

Tags: nvidia, acpi, recovery-mode, gpu-driver, modprobe

I've been having serious trouble getting the Nvidia drivers working on my machine with Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10. My graphics card is an RTX 2080 and my machine is an ASUS desktop. I've been getting the typical errors when modprobe fails to properly loads the Nvidia kernel module, such as repeated warnings on the start-up splash screen about the nvidia persistence daemon failing to start and `nvidia-smi` throwing the error

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

In /var/log/syslog, I see the following information

```
kernel: [  127.697714] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510
kernel: [  127.698904] NVRM: Can't find an IRQ for your NVIDIA card!
kernel: [  127.698905] NVRM: Please check your BIOS settings.
kernel: [  127.698905] NVRM: [Plug & Play OS] should be set to NO
kernel: [  127.698905] NVRM: [Assign IRQ to VGA] should be set to YES 
kernel: [  127.698907] nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1
kernel: [  127.698915] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
kernel: [  127.698915] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA devices were initialized.
kernel: [  127.699812] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 510
systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Finished Rotate log files.
systemd-udevd[381]: nvidia: Process '/sbin/modprobe nvidia-uvm' failed with exit code 1.
systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
nvidia-persistenced: Verbose syslog connection opened
nvidia-persistenced: Now running with user ID 126 and group ID 133
nvidia-persistenced: Started (5625)
dbus-daemon[5486]: dbus[5486]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
```

The things I've immediately done and checked off were

1. Verified secure boot is disabled in the BIOS.
2. Checked to make sure there are no issues with the modprobe blacklists, both in /lib and /etc
3. Used nvidia-prime to make sure the system is configured to use Nvidia instead of Intel.
4. Purged and reinstalled the nvidia drivers. I've tried both the 460 and 450 drivers.

I've also tried installing the drivers using the .run installer files Nvidia provides instead of using the distro-provided install options, but I still receive the same errors. I originally was running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and I've even done a dist-upgrade and upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10 in case that would change anything. Using the new Linux kernel 5.8 instead of 5.4, the Nvidia driver still does not properly function.

However, strangely, when I choose to launch the recovery mode option in Grub, and then boot from recovery options screen, the drivers work perfectly! I cannot figure out what makes the drivers work when I start Recovery Mode first.

I do have my grub file edited to launch the Linux kernel with the options `noresume acpi=off` to deal with some issues with ACPI, in the off chance that might be relevant.

For now, a temporary fix is to simply launch Recovery Mode first before a normal desktop session. However, I would like to figure out what is going on. Can anyone help me pinpoint what the exact issue is, and if it's possible to resolve it?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?